# Parse to 5 decimals but get floating number back. Return decimals also for >1

Tags: android, floating-point, numbers, number-formatting, decimalformat

So the server needs me to send a floating point number (2.00, 0.1234) With a maximum of 5 decimals.
Some data that I get have more. so I used a decimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00000");
params.put("rate", Float.parseFloat(decimalFormat.format(mileageRate.getMax_value())));
```

The issue is that for 2 it will become "2.00000" which parsed to float returns 2, which gets my this error:

```
{"rate":["`rate` must be a floating point number!"]}
```

This is the request with Float.parseFloat:

```
{"mileage_rate":{"currency":"EUR","name":"red","unit":"km","rate":2,"tag":"commuted"},"user_vehicles":{"ids":[]}}
```

This is without (just decimalFormat):

```
{"mileage_rate":{"currency":"EUR","name":"work","unit":"km","rate":"2.00000","tag":"work"},"user_vehicles":{"ids":[]}}
```

Both return the same error. Now this was fixed on the server side. But still, for the future, is it possible to set nr of decimals to a float? NOT STRING

Comment: Can you provide declaration of parms variable.?

Comment: @WaleedSarwar does this helps? provide to whom? The server needs that exact type of request to be sent